# PHP FileUpload error

Tags: php

What's wrong with this?

```or-tag-here
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/api/member_settings_profile_avatar.php">
    <input type="file" name="settings_choose_avatar" id="settings_choose_avatar">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

php/api/member_settings_profile_avatar.php, line 2:

```php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["settings_choose_avatar"]["tmp_name"], "img/test.png");
```

I get the following error upon submitting a valid .png file:

```
 Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/test.png): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory in /customers/4/1/a/mysitenamehere.com/httpd.www/php/api
/member_settings_profile_avatar.php on line 2 Warning: move_uploaded_file():
 Unable to move '/customers/4/1/a/mysitenamehere.com/tmp/phpeN9wyk' to 
'img/test.png' in /customers/4/1/a/mysitenamehere.com/httpd.www/php/api
/member_settings_profile_avatar.php on line 2
```

Is it an issue with my host or what?

Comment: Does the path exist? Have you created the path before trying to upload (mkdir)? Is the path right?

Comment: If both answers to @TopQuestions questions are yes, have you check `is_writable` on the folder?

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct, do you want to store the image in the `/php/api/img` folder or did you perhaps mean `/img` (all relative to the web-root)?

Comment: I changed it to /img, same result. The img folder exists in the root.

Comment: What about the rights? See @TomHart

Comment: The root of the web-server is not the same as the root of the file system. Where do you want to store the image?

Comment: Hi can you post the complete upload.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the path of the destination should be relative to the root of the website. You can do it with  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and adding the path to the folder where you want to upload the file.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["settings_choose_avatar"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/test.png");
```

It will work if your current php file is at the website's root folder.